# factory reset of a Huawei Ascend H881C

Tags: factory-reset, huawei

My google play store is not working. Every time I go to download an app, it says no connectivity. I was told that I would have to reset my phone, but I'm scared that it will delete everything. I can't download backup apps because I can't even get on google play. I'm really sad and frustrated because I don't know what to do. Please help! Thanks. (:

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to do this :
Go to setting > manage application> google playstore > clear data

if that wont stop your problem,

you can download BackUp apps from many other sites on line.
try 1mobile market or MoboMarket etc.

If your phone is rooted, try titanium backup
http://www.papktop.com/titanium-backup-%e2%98%85-root-5-5-0-1.html

You need to enable 'Unknown Sources' in Setting > Security tab in order to install apps not from play store.